# Can we used Blink layout engine for webview in android?

Tags: android-webview

The default browser on stock Android is Google Chrome. This uses the Blink layout engine. For AOSP installations without the Google Apps, the default browser is the old "Browser" app that uses Webkit.

Can we used the Blink engine for webview in android .